# Error: Could not find or load main class with

Tags: java, gradle

I know this question has been asked a million times but I can't seem to find a way to solve it.

The problem is that when I run my JAR file `java -jar MYFATJAR.jar` using:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191-1-ojdkbuild"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-1-ojdkbuild-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class PACKAGE_PATH.MAINCLASSNAME
```

But when I run the same command with:

```
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)
```

The jar runs fine.

I compile the JAR using Gradle. Here's the shortened `build.grade` file:

```
// build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes (
                "Main-Class": "org.me.logreader.App",
                "Specification-Title": "Log Reader",
                "Specification-Vendor" : "ME",
                "Implementation-Title"   : "Log Reader",
                "Implementation-Vendor" : "ME"
        )
    }

    archiveName = "LogReader.jar"
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}

...
```

If I open the JAR with WinRAR, I see it displayed this way:
[image]

The project structure is as follows:

```
src
   -main
        -java
           -org.me.logreader
               -controllers
               -model
               -parsers
               -version
               -views
               -workers
               App.java
```

**UPDATE**
The contents of the `MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Log Reader
Specification-Vendor: ME
Specification-Title: Log Reader
Main-Class: org.kobbigal.logreader.App
Implementation-Vendor: ME
```

Comment: inside the jar file there should be a file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. What is the content of this file?

Comment: @gimby - I've updated the question with the manifest contents.

Comment: All looks fine assuming the 'me' in other sections of your question is actually a redacted version of the 'kobbigal' in your MANIFEST.MF. Can you even run anything else using the openjdk build?

Comment: @gimby - Good catch about the manifest vendor :) Other JARs are running fine.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that this is a JavaFX application while the other JAR is not? @Gimby

Comment: Eh, you didn't say anything about there being two jars. Your question mentions two JDKs and makes absolutely no mention of there being two different programs being run.

Comment: @gimby - The application doesn't have two JARs. I meant the JAR that I used to test whether the openJDK build will run any JAR.